# ICEfaces runtime error: "WriteText method cannot write null text"

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, icefaces, icefaces-3

My Java EE web application deploys fine, but whenever I try to load a page, it comes out totally blank and I get the following stack trace in the server log:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException: WriteText method cannot write null text
    at org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.writeText(DOMResponseWriter.java:308)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:80)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:348)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:343)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.renderAnchor(MenuItemRenderer.java:697)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuItemRenderer.encodeBegin(MenuItemRenderer.java:219)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:334)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.menubar.MenuBarRenderer.encodeChildren(MenuBarRenderer.java:100)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RendererWrapper.encodeChildren(RendererWrapper.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

ICEfaces 3.0.0 on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 (Mojarra 2.1.6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a new JSF converter whose `@FacesConverter` annotation was missing its value attribute. In other words, I had annotated my converter class with `@FacesConverter` instead of `@FacesConverter("myNewConverter")`. Once I added in the value attribute to the annotation, it ran fine.